# Android OpenGL previous frame re-appear for split moment when calling update

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have just started using the OpenGL ES 2 for android for my little game and have encountered a problem on redrawing the screen on each frame.

I have setup a loop on my Renderer's onDrawFrame, just a simple [ updateGameLogic() -> drawGame() ] or Thread.sleep() loop based on the time lapsed from last drawGame call.

Currently the updateGameLogic() method simply translate the camera to the +ve X direction (the game is 2d).

In the drawGame() call, I first clear my screen with GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT). Then I have 3 glBindTexture and glDrawElements calls for drawing 3 categories of objects with different texture atlas.

Here comes the problem, in between each frame drawn on screen, there is a blink of the previous frame appearing which is undesired and makes the game look dizzy. Precisely, say the game is just about to draw frame 3 from frame 2, right before frame 2 vanish and frame 3 appearing, there is a split moment where frame 1 is displayed.

I thought this may be due to the way the GLSurfaceView is buffered by the system so I experimented with calling multiple glClear before drawing but everything stays the same.  Would be grateful if someone can provide some explanation / solution to the problem, and what I have done wrong, thanks. (basically paragraph 2 to 4 is all my code so I have not posted it, unless requested)

Comment: Request for clarification: You say that you "setup a loop" in `onDrawFrame()`. Do you actually have a loop in that method? Or do you just draw one frame every time the method is called?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. My bad on wording, there is no actual loop inside the method, the loop "exists" in the sense that onDrawFrame would be called repeatedly by the system.  My onDrawFrame() starts with an IF statement such that it goes to Thread.sleep() is called if the time from last time render took place is less than 33ms and return void. I wait until Android call onDrawFrame() again to actually draw (again subject to the IF above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the clarification in the comment, it sounds like you have something like this in your code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    long deltaTime = currentTime - mLastFrameTime;
    if (deltaTime < 33) {
        Thread.sleep(33 - deltaTime);
        return;
    }

    mLastFrameTime = currentTime;

    updateGameLogic(deltaTime);
    drawGame();
}
```

This will indeed cause problems. When `onDrawFrame()` is called, you **have to** render a frame. You can't just return without drawing anything. The caller will assume that you rendered a frame in any case, and it will end up being presented on the screen. If you decide not to render anything, whatever happened to be in the surface you were supposed to draw to will be presented. There's no telling what this will be, but it's quite likely that it's an old frame from 2-3 frames earlier.

If you want to artificially throttle the frame rate, e.g. to save power, unfortunately there's no very good way to do this in Android. Using sleeps in `onDrawFrame()` is kind of dirty (and inherently unreliable, IMHO), but it might be necessary in this case. The key is that either before or after you sleep, you still need to render a frame. As a first attempt, I would try tweaking the above to something like this:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    long deltaTime = currentTime - mLastFrameTime;
    if (deltaTime < 33) {
        Thread.sleep(33 - deltaTime);
        currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        deltaTime = currentTime - mLastFrameTime;
    }

    mLastFrameTime = currentTime;

    updateGameLogic(deltaTime);
    drawGame();
}
```

Note that while there is still an artificial delay, there is no early `return` in the code anymore.

There are probably more robust variations of this idea for throttling the redraws to 30 fps. Some searching on SO or the rest of the internet should reveal previous discussions.

Comment: Lovely, I basically ported my code previous used on SurfaceView which used the mechanism I had not knowing the renderer of GLSurfaceView doesn't like it. Its working nice and smooth now after some tweaks.  I'm surprised though such behavior was not mentioned in the various tutorials that I have read online.